# Unversion folder of working copy - TortoiseSVN 1.7

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I unversion a subfolder in my working copy of tortoiseSVN? 
I found that guide http://tortoisesvn.net/unversion.html but it did not work for me.

Comment: How do you need to *unversion* a subfolder? It you have committed the folder int to the repository, you need to delete it from the repository.

Comment: The folder must be stay in the repository. It contains database files that i did not need, they are very big and need a lot of space on my SSD. I try the Export to the same location, but i looks like that this works only for pre 1.7 version of tortoise before they update the working copy structure (only one .svn folder in the root).

Comment: Can you use the svn command line? On the command line the answer is: `svn del --keep-local SUBDIR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this folder needs to remain easily available in the repository, and just not in your working copy, what you want is a [Sparse Checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) (see also http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth).

Check out the parent folder (or project root), but not at full depth. Then update each subfolder with the appropriate depth, omitting the one you don't want in your WC.